# Coronavirus vaccine distribution restrictions in the USA

Tags: united-states, covid-19, vaccine

Each US state is required to develop a detailed plan for distribution of Coronavirus vaccine. Those plans were due on Nov 1 2020.

It appears that the vaccine distribution to the more generalized public (e.g. seniors without co-morbidity complications) will be regulated by each one of the states. The state plans that I've seen appear emphasize protection (by way of vaccine distribution) to it's residents. Vaccination records will be maintained by the state.

*So where does that leave longer-term tourists that are non-residents?*

Tens of millions of seniors (of varying health conditions) will spend the first four months of 2021 out-of-state. Will they be required to return to their permanent residence sate to be vaccinated?

I have not found any discussion on this -- perhaps SE members have.

Comment: Asking what will happen is asking about predictions of future evens. I think this question can be worded differently in a way that is on-topic (i.e., doesn't ask about future events), but the way it is currently worded is borderline off-topic. Particularly the title.

Comment: @Chipster States and the CDC should be publishing their vaccine distribution plans – an answer would draw on those published plans

Comment: @Chipster, each state was to develop plans to distribute, using a CDC template, to answer questions about the state's plan. I think New Jersey was one of the first plans published on October 16. More recently these 50+ plans were required to be in place. So, the title question "Will..." is intended to reflect those plans. However, to satisfy your concern of a "future" event, I will modify the title question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume this will vary on a state-by-state basis, but at least in Florida, non-residents will get the vaccine at the same time as residents:

> When it comes to the vaccine for COVID-19, snowbirds are equal to the rest of us.
>
> Senior visitors spending the winter in Florida, along with seniors who live in the state full-time and those with medical conditions, [can get the vaccine here sometime in the coming months](https://www.sun-sentinel.com/coronavirus/fl-ne-qanda-vaccine-plan-south-florida-ss-prem-20201212-szqkmhh7pfhlveahessk7voizq-story.html), said Jason Mahon, spokesman for the Florida Division of Emergency Management. They’re scheduled for the next round of inoculations after health care workers and residents of long-term care facilities.
>
> The Centers for Disease Control and Prevention makes it clear in its “Florida Interim COVID-19 Vaccination Plan” that you don’t have to be a full-time Floridian to get your inoculation: “The goal of the Florida COVID-19 Mass Vaccination plan is to immunize all Floridians and visitors who choose to be vaccinated.”
>
> [Yes, snowbirds will be able to get a COVID-19 vaccine in Florida – SOUTH FLORIDA SUN SENTINEL, DEC 15, 2020](https://www.sun-sentinel.com/coronavirus/fl-ne-seniors-want-vaccine-20201215-xjoyl3e5cfclrbtxf34d5cjgbq-story.html)

This is particularly relevant for Florida, as the number of retirees who spend their winters in the state gives it a particularly large population of high-risk, non-residents. I would imagine, though, that other states would likely make a similar calculation that it's best to allocate vaccine doses based on what they determine to be the best interests of the state, regardless of residency status.

Comment: Great link! - had not seen that yet